# Asterisk invalid Hangup cause

Tags: asterisk, adhearsion

I am using Adhearsion on top of Asterisk (version 11.9.0).

To make outbound calls Adhearsion uses AMI originate command. Problem is Asterisk doesn't say why the call got hung up. 
If the callee is busy or did not pick up the call or hung up the call or switched off i am getting the same reason code ( 0 ).

Is there a way to get different Hung up reasons?

Answer (score 1):

You can do originate to channel like Local/number@some_context/n

After that you can write some_context to dialout and handle in that context usual way any dial cause.